# Debug assemblies without PDB

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a Project built in .Net framework where in we use reflection to call some methods in DLL which are created using older version of the code. Now, in one particular scenario, one of the method is failing and there is no stack trace which point to exact root cause of the issue. 
 I don't have the pdb files for these DLL. Is it somehow possible to debug the assembly code or get the exact stack trace from the target assembly without having PDB files. I don't want to go back to the old version of the code and generate Pdb files every time I encounter such issues.

I found some tools like PDBDownloader but that is used to download PDB files only for microsoft assemblies but I couldn't find any tool that can generate PDB from my assembly.

Comment: [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html) can be used as a dynamic symbol server, decompiling DLLs on the fly. The PDBs vary in usefulness depending on obfuscation and optimization levels.

Comment: Awesome. Its working. Thanks a lot